# Python Selenium skip to next step if not found

Tags: python, selenium, bots, instagram

I've made a simple IG bot that goes to indicated tag, goes post by post, likes, and follow the poster. But sometimes Instagram crashes and doesn't show the post - then script also crashes because it can't find a follow/like button.

Can I make a loop or something else if the button is not found, click the next post button? I'm totally new to python and I cant figure it out.

Here's my code:

```
# Following the poster
        if followtag:
            self.Wait(1,2)
            temp = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/article/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/button')
            if (temp.text == "Obserwuj") and (name not in self.doNotFollowList):
                temp.click()
                self.AddFollowedList(name)
                self.AddDoNotFollowList(name)
                print("[{}] *followed* {}".format(i+1, name))

# Go to the next post
        if i == 0:
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/div/button').click()
        else:
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button').click()
```

Comment: You can add an `try/except` statement - More about try except: [w3schools.com/python-try-except](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp), could you also add your full code, I will take a look a it

Comment: What is this condition `if i == 0:` ? What is `i` ?

Comment: @xtekky i've created github repo with all code, it will be easier to understand. Code is too long to post here https://github.com/Mkzz1/instabot/blob/master/bot.py

Comment: @Mkzz you could use the [instapy](https://pypi.org/project/instapy/) library to do what you want to achieve, which is going to be much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work, It will try to follow and if i doesn't work, go to the next post.

```py
    try:
        # Following the poster
        if followtag:
            self.Wait(1,2)
            temp = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/article/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/button')
            if (temp.text == "Obserwuj") and (name not in self.doNotFollowList):
                temp.click()
                self.AddFollowedList(name)
                self.AddDoNotFollowList(name)
                print("[{}] *followed* {}".format(i+1, name))

    except:
        # Go to the next post
        if i == 0:
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/div/button').click()
        else:
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button').click()
```

Comment: It works! Just changed except to only - except: self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button').click() and it works perfect now. Thanks for your help!